# How to show Flutter Widget documentation with Visual Studio Code IntelliSense?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So, how can I show a **Widget** Documentation with VSCode auto complete? As we can see [in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Evt.png), when hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> with Android Studio and typing in a widget, it'll show its documentation.
However, I couldn't find a way in Visual Studio Code to show a Widget documentation, only [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT32j.png).

I know it's possible to hover the mouse over the Widget, but I don't want to read its doc after typing it, but instead, before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select any line of code & press "ctrl" + "space", & it looks like:
[image: Widget documentation]